# how to know whether volume is online or not by using diskpart command

Tags: windows-server-2003

I want to know whether volume is online or not by using diskpart command in windows 2003 server 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Run Diskpart:
list volume
select volume [Volume you are checking]
detail volume

This should show you the status of that volume and all disks in the volume if it is a dynamic volume.